# Play only one action at a time

Tags: animation

When i make an action, push it, then make a new one, the keyframes from the other actions are still playing, and blending with the new one, how could i play only the new one?

Answer (score 2):

**Mute the [NLA](https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/editors/nla/tracks.html#tracks)**

[image]

Can mute the entire [NLA](https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/editors/nla/tracks.html#tracks) stack using toggle, as shown in image, or via scripting by setting the object's animation data [`use_nla`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.AnimData.html?highlight=use_nla#bpy.types.AnimData.use_nla) property. When muted will only evaluate the active action. I call this the one in the "slot", that displays keyframes in action editor / dope sheet.

```
>>> C.object.animation_data.use_nla
True

>>> C.object.animation_data.use_nla = False
>>> C.object.animation_data.use_nla
False
```

A muted [NLA](https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/editors/nla/tracks.html#tracks) stack is a convenient way to store actions with an association to their target object, mesh, shape etc.

Note also: NLA tracks can be muted individually via the similar mute button on each track.